# Force Google Doc to open without Print Layout view

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Writing guides in Google Docs and sharing them with other people as read-only is great. However, even when formatting it without the "Print Layout" option (the first toggle option under View menu), every viewer opening the document will see it in Print Layout, i.e. with half-empty pages before each page break. This is very annoying.

Is there any way to default the Print Layout to be switched OFF when a read-only viewer opens a Google Doc? Here are 2 ways for which I'm hoping:

- via a URL parameter, so that the link I share determines the document will open with a switched-off Print Layout;
- in Google Apps Script, with something like `function onOpen(){ DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().setPrintLayout(false); }` 
  *(except `setPrintLayout()` does not seem to exist right now)*.

I'm mostly interested in the web browser version, and in the mobile app too (though less).

There's a similar question [over there](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79549/exiting-print-layout-when-viewing-a-read-only-google-doc) (with screenshots).

And there's a [discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Kp-wyBdipjA) dating back when switching off Print Layout in read-only Google Docs was not yet possible (it is, now, though only manually).